# Cannot change the global variable using the Firebase method .forEach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm programming my Login module so that when the user enters the username and password, it will get the input and process it in the javascript. I used the .forEach function so that the username and password will look for its matching user and store it's unique key in the GLOBAL VARIABLE so that I can use it later for data manipulation for the logged in user.

First, I declared the variable currentKey outside the the function. 
`var currentKey = "";`

then the login function, looks like this:

```js
function logIn(){
 var loggedUname = $("#loginUname").val();
 var loggedPword = $("#loginPword").val();
 
 var tailorRef = firebase.database().ref('tailors');
 
 tailorRef.on('value', function(data){
  data.forEach(function(childData){
   if ( (loggedUname == childData.val().tUsername) && (loggedPword == childData.val().tPassword) ){
    currentKey = childData.key;
   }
  });
  alert(currentKey);
 });
 
}
```

If I press the login button after entering the registered username and password, it displays the corresponding key via alert.

But when I place the `alert(currentKey);` outside the .on() method like this:

```js
tailorRef.on('value', function(data){
  data.forEach(function(childData){
   if ( (loggedUname == childData.val().tUsername) && (loggedPword == childData.val().tPassword) ){
    currentKey = childData.key;
   }
  });
 });
 alert(currentKey);
```

...the currentKey is displayed as UNDEFINED!

I tried making a set function inside the .forEach , but it's still the same. I'm guessing that the unique key is not stored properly in the global variable currentKey.

Anyone knows what's happening in my code?

**EDIT: Sorry that I didn't state my main problem here earlier. What I want is for the key inside the .forEach to be stored in the global var currentKey, so that when I alert outside the function, the key will still be there at the var currentKey. My plan is to use the stored key in other functions in my javascript, not just inside the logIn() function. So I thought declaring the var outside the function will make it globally usable and updatable. How do I make the corresponding key to be globally usable in my javascript file?**

Comment: Basically, tailorRef.on is an asynchronous call and the function gets called when it's finished. If you put alert(currentKey); outside the function it will always get called first and at that point currentKey is undefined. You should leave it within the function. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @camen_kid I want the key inside the .forEach to be stored in the global var currentKey, so that when I alert outside the function, the key will still be there at the var currentKey. My plan is to use the stored key in other functions in my javascript, not just inside the logIn() function. So I thought declaring the var outside the function will make it globally usable and updatable.

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase (and pretty much any modern web API) asynchronously. The global variable is modified just fine by your code, but only **after** you printed its value. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen based on my inspection on that question, I think the "Promise" technology is the way to handle my problem at this point.