# Firebase data returning an UNDEFINED value even though it has content

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Coming from my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553607/cannot-change-the-global-variable-using-the-firebase-method-foreach-in-javascri) in this site (before I resort to the "Promise" technology), I came up an idea of storing the variable in the firebase database instead of making it a global var in the javascript so that I can use it in any function (even though in an asynchronous one). So I made this code:

```js
function logIn(){
 var loggedUname = $("#loginUname").val();
 var loggedPword = $("#loginPword").val();
 
 var tailorRef = firebase.database().ref('tailors');
 var keyRef = firebase.database().ref();
 
 tailorRef.on('value', function(data){
  data.forEach(function(childData){
   if ( (loggedUname == childData.val().tUsername) && (loggedPword == childData.val().tPassword) ){
    currentKey = childData.key;
   }
  });
  keyRef.update({currentTailor: currentKey});
  alert("key = " + keyRef.currentTailor);
 });
 
}
```

the .update method was successful since it stored the corresponding key for the logged in user:

[the updated database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI01E.png)

but when I try to retrieve it using alert, it says UNDEFINED! I don't understand because I'm assuming that I'm calling from the root reference of the database, that's as low as I go.

I tried making a seperate .on() function for the keyRef, but it's still the same result.

```js
keyRef.on('value', function(data){
  alert(data.currentTailor);
});
```

Did I called the data in a wrong way?

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but I'll bet `keyRef.update()` is asynchronous.

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html try using the .then(function(){ alert()}) way

Comment: @Barmar I used the .update() in my signUp function and I succesfully retrieved the data that were stored in this login() function. If it were what you said, I shouldn't have able to retrieve the tUsername and tPassword in this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be:

```
keyRef.on('value', function(data){
 //  alert(data.val().currentTailor); see the difference 
     console.log('currentTailor ==>', data.val().currentTailor);
});
```

`alert()` in javascript is not recommended as it freezes your page. Use console instead. This way you can see your logs in browser's console (in chrome press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

> Firebase's **on()** method [returns the callback function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on) . To get the data object, you have to use **val()** method on that return value. Then you can get any value using corresponding key.

```
 keyRef.on('value', function(data){
// here data is callback function
});

keyRef.on('value', function(data){
//data.val() returns the data in object form
});
 keyRef.on('value', function(data){
 // data.val().currentTailor to access currentTailor attribute
 });
```

You can console each of them to see what is the return values.

Comment: oh, it worked! I always thought that when you have a single value in the root , I won't need the .val() and can call it directly with it's value name. I was wrong. thank you.