# Data from Firebase in Browser shows fine but in html page shows as undefined

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have data downloaded from firebase DB and the data is fine but when this data is loaded into HTML all table TD shows undefined, not able to understand why been check a whole lot of codes not able to understand whats wrong here.

Thank You

```
var registration = firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION")

dataRef = firebase.database().ref().child("REGISTRATION");

dataRef.on("value", rData);

function rData(data){

    console.log(data.val());
    var gData = data.val();
        for (gDatarow in gData)
    {
    alert(email);
        var email = gDatarow.email;
        var name = gDatarow.name;
        var gender = gDatarow.gender;
        var date = gDatarow.date;
        var phone = gDatarow.phone;
        var state = gDatarow.state;
        var school = gDatarow.school;
        var clas = gDatarow.clas;
        var classname = gDatarow.classname;
        $("#reData").append("<tr><td>" + email + "</td></td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td></td>" + date + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td></td>" + state + "</td><td>" + school + "</td></td>" + clas + "</td><td>" + classname + "</td></tr>");    

}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1lXT.png)

Comment: What is the console output of console.log(data.val())?

Comment: And ist there any good reason not to use a "for (gDataRow in gData)"?

Comment: Sorry I had uploaded an image as well but not showing...you mean a for loop ?

Comment: Yes. Seems simpler.

Comment: Still getting undefined, this is the image of data in the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1lXT.png

Comment: YOu have a line in there: `console.log(data.val());`. So go into the console (F12 in a browser) and take a look - what is it outputting?

Comment: This is my output in the console

KEG8tn1-nEDfZLAwAD
:
{Birthday: "10-dec-1984", Class: "X", Classname: "Science", Email: "khlkhljk@yahoo.com", Gender: "MALE", …}
-KuEGGyZYX9nu07i3Wp0
:
{Birthday: "10-dec-1984", Class: "Central School", Classname: "Science", Email: "iiiiiii@yahoo.com", Gender: "FEMALE", …}
-KuEXumI_Z3tY3ytA_90
:
{Birthday: "23432432423", Class: "OnlineLearningPortal", Classname: "Tomato", Email: "yyyyyy@yahoo.com", Gender: "FEMALE", …}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Have you noticed that your field names in the code all start with lowercase letters but the JSON you posted has Email, Birthday etc. They start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks, changed all to lower case still shows as undefined in html...

Comment: I did a bit of debugging from within firefox and there seems to be some issue in variables email, name etc or childnodes,...as fire fox shows data in gData and gDatarow in the debugger...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase data returning an UNDEFINED value even though it has content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560959/firebase-data-returning-an-undefined-value-even-though-it-has-content)

Comment: Appreciate it @bummi thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in my case :

```
dataRef.on("child_added", function(data) {
    var rData = data.val();
$("#reData").append("<tr><td>" + rData.email + "</td><td>" + rData.name + "</td><td>" + rData.gender + "</td><td>" + rData.birthdate + "</td><td>" + rData.phone + "</td><td>" + rData.state + "</td><td>" + rData.school + "</td><td>" + rData.class + "</td><td>" + rData.classname + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Thanks to all for their time.